# How to keep user logged in even when Application closed SQL C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows App Project to which users can login with their userid and passwords. I use SQL for this purpose. I want to make it so that when a user logs in and quits from application the application will ask login details only if he logged out. If he closes the application without logging out, the login window is not shown. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How are you managing UserId and Passwords? Custom build? Active Directory?  Is this for internal customers only?

Comment: with an sql connection

Comment: Can we assume that each user would have their own Windows account? If so, I’d look at linking the Windows user account to the users record in the database.

Comment: it is not about windows account , it is like auto login or something like that , i don't know how in another way to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, just adding a setting won't work.

If the userids and passwords are stored in a  SQL DataTable, you can add another bool column and update that column.

For e.g., you have a user named ABC. When he logins, a value of true is set against the userid of ABC in the SQL DataTable. Whenever the Application loads or the Form is shown, it is checked if ABC had logged in or not(remember that we have  bool column to check from) and if it is true, the login window is never shown.

This could be an easier, feasible and secure solution.

**EDIT:**

Please use the below link to view a guide to adding columns to SQL datatable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX8-LhgFnUU

But instead of adding 3 columns as shown in the video, add 4 columns and name the 4th column as 'Logged' and set its type to bool.

Also, pls edit the code shown in the video as below(you can also copy and paste this)

```
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Do Not Delete\LoginApp\DB\LoginDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Logged";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    
    sqlConnection1.Close();

    DataRow drow = dt.Rows[0];
    bool value = drow.Field<bool>("Logged");

if(value == false)
{
   SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Do Not Delete\LoginApp\DB\LoginDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            string query = "Select * from tbl_Login Where username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                dtbl.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = true;
                sda.Update(dtPrimary);
                sqlcon.Close();
                frmMain objFrmMain = new frmMain();
                this.Hide();
                objFrmMain.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check your username and password");
            }
}
else
{
                frmMain objFrmMain = new frmMain();
                this.Hide();
                objFrmMain.Show();
}
```

Comment: @ArifYavuz06:  Have you made the SQL datatable yourself? If yes, you must be knowing how to add columns to a datatable. Just add another column of type 'bool' and when the user logs in (e.g. after clicking the login button) add a 'true' value for that user in the bool column. When he logs out, change the value to 'false'. If you don't know how to do this, let me know and I will help you to code this.

Comment: Could you help me with that please

Comment: @D J, Are you still here to help me with my project ,

Comment: @ArifYavuz06: Yea. I will surely do it today.

Comment: @ArifYavuz06: Pls try the **EDIT:** section and revert back.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @ArifYavuz06: Glad to know that this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can save login user name and keep login checkbox state in xml file (not recommended ) or bin file (recommended) or in properties settings (best way) and retrieve the values with if conditions
LOGINBUTTON :

```
If(keeplogin_checkbox=checked)
    {
     Properties.settings.default.username=username_textbox.text;
     Properties.settings.default.keeplogin=true;
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
     }else
     {Properties.settings.default.keeplogin=false;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); 
      }
```

When you check on keep login checkbox and login first login will keep state in settings

Then you go to code in programs.cs file
To determine from any form starting from main form or login form depend on test value in properties settings keeplogin value

```
 if (Properties.Settings.Default.keeplogin == false)
        {
         Application.Run(new LOGIN_FORM());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new MAIN_FORM());
        }
    }
```

after that you can create logout button in the main form :

```
        {
        Properties.Settings.Default.username = " ";
        Properties.Settings.Default.keeplogin = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Comment: While this should work, it has pretty significant potential security implications, especially depending on where it is saved. Any user or process that can access that file can impersonate the user without question. At minimum, setting permissions on the file to only allow read by the executing user at least reduces the possibility of attack to processes executing with that user's account or anything with administrator or SYSTEM account access. Encrypting it with the user's private key would reduce it further to only that user.

Comment: sure ,
any operations with any type of files such as xml or bin it's less secure just we can use encrypt user key , but when use properties settings value we don't need encrypt key

Answer (score 0):

One way you go about this is to store a session token as an [application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview) variable which can be checked on runtime. How you would go about generating it will depend on the scope of the application (server-side authentication or a local check).

Comment: To clarify, applications settings variables can be created by right-clicking on the project (not the Solution at the top, the folder itself) in the tree and clicking Properties, and you'll have a Settings tab to access it and create new variables. Also worth while to mention this isn't the most secure way to store a token but it gets the job done.